# elasticsearch - fulltext search for words with special/reserved characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing documents that may contain any special/reserved characters in their fulltext body. For example
"PDF/A is an ISO-standardized version of the Portable Document Format..."

I would like to be able to search for `pdf/a` without having to escape the forward slash.

How should i analyze my query-string and what type of query should i use?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? What do your mappings and query look like as a starting point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support queries containing reserved characters i now use the **`Simple Query String Query`** (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html)

As of not using a query parser it is a bit limited (e.g. no field-queries like `id:5`), but it solves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The default `standard` analyzer will tokenize a string like that so that "PDF" and "A" are separate tokens.  The "A" token might get cut out by the stop token filter (See [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html)).  So without any custom analyzers, you will typically get any documents with just "PDF".

You can try creating your own analyzer modeled off the `standard` analyzer that includes a [Mapping Char Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html).  The idea would that "PDF/A" might get transformed into something like "pdf_a" at index and query time.  A simple match query will work just fine.  But this is a very simplistic approach and you might want to consider how '/' characters are used in your content and use slightly more complex regex filters which are also not perfect solutions.

Sorry, I completely missed your point about having to escape the character.  Can you elaborate on your use case if this turns out to not be helpful at all?